# Flutter Firestore "_CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)" Error

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting an error like this:

[image]

Why could this be? How can I solve it?

Codes:

```
FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

// ...

_auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
  email: _emailController.text,
  password: _passwordController.text,
);
_firestore.collection("Users").doc(_auth.currentUser!.uid).set({
  "ID": _auth.currentUser?.uid,
  "Email": _emailController.text,
  "Phone": _phoneController.text,
  "Name": _nameController.text,
  "Surname": _surnameController.text,
  "Photo": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/teen-software-stock-tracking.appspot.com/o/default.jpg?alt=media&token=0eec2e1f-2ccf-4bda-8664-3d3f018621b3",
  "Level": 0,
  "ProductRight": 10,
  "AddedProduct": 0,
});
```

User is created in Firebase Auth but I can't write data to Firestore.

Comment: When you use `!` on a variable, you're telling the compiler: "look, this thing to the left of the `!` will never be `null`". And the error message points out that you broke that promise, as the `currentUser` is `null`. It might be good to check the result you get back from `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`, which includes the `user` too if the creation succeeded.

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen thanks.

Comment: I have posted frank comment as  [community wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki),so that other's could spot the workaround easier

Answer (score 0):

Answering as community wiki as Frank already mentioned in comments:

When you use ! on a variable, you're telling the compiler: "look, this thing to the left of the ! will
never be null". And the error message points out that you broke that promise, as the
currentUser is null. It might be good to check the result you get back from
createUserWithEmailAndPassword, which includes the user too if the creation succeeded.